# ProcessPoolExecutor within class object Python.causes : cannot pickle 'weakref' object

Tags: python, multithreading, process

I have the following piece of code, which throws 'cannot pickle 'weakref' object'.

I've seen tons of examples, where people wrap the ProcessPoolExecutor with a `if __name__ == '__main__'`, however this is not possible in my class. There are no examples on how to use a ProcessPoolExecutor in a python class.

For reference, the ThreadPoolExecutor works fine.

Anyone knows how to do this?

The stack trace is:

```
  File "C:\Users\mikke\ALG_EXP\ThreeSum\pythonSol\Implementations\near_linear_alg\RandomizedMultiThreaded.py", line 35, in fasterSubsetSum
    S = self.sumSet(S, f.result(), t)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 239, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

And the code is:

```
import concurrent.futures
import math
import threading

import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from Implementations.helpers.Helper import toNumbers
from Implementations.near_linear_alg.RandomizedBase import NearLinearBase


class RandomizedMultiThreaded(NearLinearBase):

    def __init__(self, debug):
        super().__init__(debug, 0)
        self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=12)

    def fasterSubsetSum(self, Z, t, delta):
        n = len(Z)
        self.n = n
        Z = np.array(Z)
        Zi = self.partitionIntoLayers(Z, n, t)
        S = [1]
        if len(Zi[0]) > 1:
            S = Zi[0]
        futures = list()
        for i in range(1, len(Zi)):
            z = np.array(Zi[i])
            if len(z) > 1:
                if len(z) > 1:
                    ans = self.executor.submit(self.ColorCodingLayerMulti, z, t, pow(2, i + 1) - 1,
                                               delta / (math.ceil(math.log2(n))))
                    futures.append(ans)
        for f in futures:
            S = self.sumSet(S, f.result(), t)
        return toNumbers(S)
```

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Windows.

So far, I've fixed the problem by removing the initialization from the __init__ function.

However, this causes some new, strange behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make the executor a member of an object that you are passing to the submit callback, since the executor cannot be serialized and sent to a different process.

So this reproduces your error:

### Throws `TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects`

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

  def compute(self, x):
    return x*x

  def run(self):
    futures = []
    for i in range(5):
      futures.append(self.executor.submit(self.compute, i))
    return sum(future.result() for future in futures)

print(Example().run())
```

You have two options to fix this:

### Solution A: Remove the executor from the class

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class Example:
  def compute(self, x):
    return x*x

  def run(self):
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    futures = []
    for i in range(5):
      futures.append(executor.submit(self.compute, i))
    return sum(future.result() for future in futures)


print(Example().run())
```

### Solution B: Don't pass self to the callback

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def compute(x):
  return x*x


class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)


  def run(self):
    futures = []
    for i in range(5):
      futures.append(self.executor.submit(compute, i))
    return sum(future.result() for future in futures)


print(Example().run())
```